# Xamarin Forms Android WebView File Upload dont work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

We are using **XAMARIN Forms** with a **Android WebView** for mobile App development. Now we are using a Kendo **File Upload** on our Site. It works fine on all other plattforms, but on the Android App the File-Upload Button isn't even clickable.

We testet serveral things:

- use a other WebView like `WebChromeClient` or `Xam.Plugin.WebView`
- set the permissions `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Could you show me some codes? So we could see what you've done.

Comment: We call the WebView right at the start of the app after the login mask, we have no additional Code. Its a normal File Input from a Webpage...

Comment: You could refer to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62284/input-type-file-doesnt-work-on-xamarin-forms-webview-android).